# How to disable tracking for all emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to disable tracking for all emails, both the future ones and the current ones (in the journeys and single sendouts)? I would like to stop tracking clicks and opens for some time

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest reviewing the [Do Not track Profile Attribute](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_do_not_track_email_opens_and_clicks.htm&type=5)

> At send time, in accounts without Do Not Track, Marketing Cloud tracking IDs are applied while rendering subscriber messages. The Do Not Track functionality adds a send-time check that honors a subscriber’s preference. For subscribers who don’t want to be tracked, the check suppresses Marketing Cloud tracking IDs from being applied to the rendered message. So, open and click events are not known.

You could set up a profile attribute and a default value of true

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to build the attribute in child business unit or only in parent?